# grep /usr/share/dict/words

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a text file:

```
Butterfly

[tab][space]Bridge

space-12234

%%%^^%^%^^%
```

I'm trying to keep only lines that contain dictionary words from the "words" file (`/usr/share/dict/words`)

Output would look like this:

```
Butterfly

[tab][space]Bridge

space-12234
```

I've tried

```
words='/usr/share/dict/words'
grep ??  $words $1 > ouputfile
```

Comment: That's a tough one as `words` file has, for example, `a` in it and that will match `ldfkalap`. If you use exact match, you lose `space-12234`. If you strip all non-alphabets, `sp123ace` will match. You need to define further what you want to match.

Comment: @JamesBrown yep thanks for that, ive updated the last text entry to a non dictionary word

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-f` option:

> ### `-f` *FILE*, `--file=`*FILE*
>
> Obtain  patterns  from  *FILE*,  one per line.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the `-e` (`--regexp`) option, search for  all  patterns given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

```
grep -f "$words" "$1" > outputfile
```

You might be also interested in `-w` and  `-F`:

> ### `-w`, `--word-regexp`
>
> Select only those lines containing matches that
>                 form whole words. The test is that the matching
>                 substring must either be at the beginning of the
>                 line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
>                 character. Similarly, it must be either at the end
>                 of the line or followed by a non-word constituent
>                 character. Word-constituent characters are letters,
>                 digits, and the underscore. This option has no
>                 effect if `-x` is also specified.
>
> ### `-F`, `--fixed-strings`
>
> Interpret  *PATTERN*  as  a  list  of  fixed  strings   (instead   of   regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

Comment: from the example above using -f will still output "ldfkalap"

Comment: @Seito: Because [alap](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alap) is a word. Use `-w` to only include whole word matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one for awk. It prints exact matches as-is but partial matches with the (*a*, actually) longest matching word after it (without any more proper definition on how to handle partial matches):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    words[tolower($1)]
    next
}
{
    if(tolower($1) in words)
        print
    else {
        for(i in words)
            if(($0~i)&&length(i)>length(best))
                best=i
        if(best) {
            print $0,best
            best=""
        }
    }
}' /usr/share/dict/words file
```

Output (with your original data):

```
Butterfly
         Bridge
space-12234 space
ldfkalap kala
```